# Access VBA TransferText Outputting Records out of Order

Tags: vba, ms-access, text, export, output

I have an MS Access application that concatenates data from multiple sources and a form, builds a table from that and then exports the table line by line to a text file which it then renames to change the extension from `.txt` to `.ipj`. The purpose of this is to create a text file which is read by our statistical process control program.

This was working for months, but it suddenly started to scramble the order of the output file about 3 weeks ago. The order of the source table and query is as I want it to look, but the output does not look like the source table or query.

I've tried both the `DoCmd.Transfertext` method and loading the table into a recordset and printing it to the file line-by-line with a `Do While Not rst.EOF` loop. Both times I get the same problem: lines in places they're not supposed to be.

I'm running MS Access 365 and it's up to date on updates.

Any suggestions to debug this problem?

Comment: A good start would be to post your code.  If you're just looking for general debugging advice that's out of scope here and there are plenty of online guides which cover that.

Comment: MS Access works with unordered sets of data, therefore is your source query being ordered explicitly with an `order by` clause?

Comment: @LeeMac This turned out to be the answer. I had to add an ID field to the table. Odd that it worked for months without one an suddenly went to hell.

Comment: @Doppelgaenger I'm glad you were able to solve the issue - I have added my comment as an answer so that the question may be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access works with **unordered datasets**: that is, unless an explicit ordering is defined by way of an `order by` clause within a query, **you cannot rely upon the order in which the records will be processed or output** by any MS Access query or method.

As such, to guarantee a consistent output, you should order your dataset by one of the fields either using a saved query with a sort order specified, or a recordset which sources records from a table by way of an SQL statement equipped with an `order by` clause.